# Why is the image of a polynomial map a Zariski closure of the domain?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

So in Algebraic Statistics by Seth Sullivant it is heavily implied, yet not proven, that the image set of a polynomial map is a Zariski closure for the domain of the mapping. Why is this? What is the connection between the smallest algebraic variety that contains a set of points and the image of a polynomial map?

Edit: It just occurred to me that I have used wrong terms, so replace "domain" with pre-image of the image set.

Comment: This is totally false.  It seems you are badly misunderstanding something or else there are major extra assumptions in the given context which you are not mentioning.

Comment: @EricWofsey I don't know what domain means, but perhaps he's confusing the 'scheme theoretic image' (i.e. if you have $\mathrm{Spec}(B)\to \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ it's the closed subscheme of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ given by $\ker(A\to B)$) and set-theroretic image. The relationship is that the former is the closure of the latter (in all reasonable situations).

Comment: @EricWofsey Here is the full theorem: "Let $I \subset \mathbb{K}[q]$ be the vanishing ideal of a variety $V \subset \mathbb{K}^{r2}$. Let $\phi$ be a polynomial map $\phi: \mathbb{K}^{r2} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}^{r1}$. Then the vanishing ideal of the Zariski closure is the elimination ideal $I(\phi(V)) = (I + I(\Gamma_{\phi}) \cap \mathbb{K}[p])$."

So here it is implied that $\phi(V)$ is a Zariski closure i.e. a closure of the domain.

Edit: See edit of main post, some confusion due to language barrier etc.